# How to hold hover box? #html, #css, #js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Please check this link https://jsfiddle.net/mth4d7xt/1/, my problem is that when and the box is on hover and change img to border box also is changing text under the img.

I want to have still box on hover when I go down and want to choose link under the img

```
<div class="container">
<article class="caption">
    <img class="caption__media" src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6088/6128773012_bd09c0bb4e_z_d.jpg" />
    <div class="caption__overlay">
        <p>
            Alaska is a U.S. state situated in the northwest extremity of the North American continent. Bordering the state is Canada to the east, the Arctic Ocean to the north, and the Pacific Ocean to the west and south, with Russia (specifically, Siberia) further west across the Bering Strait.
        </p>
    </div>
</article>
<div class="box_text">
  <div class="a">sample text</div>
  <div class="b">
    <a href="#">text</a>
    <a href="#">text</a>
    <a href="#">text</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `.container` element instead..

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.b').hide();
    $('.container').hover(function() {
        $('.a').toggle();
      $('.b').toggle();
    });
})
```

CSS:

```
.container:hover .caption::before {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.container:hover .caption .caption__overlay {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7c7LdL6a/

Answer (score 0):

bind hover to container instead of caption:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.b').hide();
    $('.container').hover(function() {
        $('.a').toggle();
      $('.b').toggle();
    });
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mth4d7xt/3/

Comment: Almost, because I want to have still white box with border.